# Vertices of Polygon

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api

I am trying to get vertices of a polygon and having some issues with it. I have PolygonN object and would like to get PointCollection and get access to each points that make up the polygon, any ideas?

```
            var records = client.QueryFeatureData(mapName, layerId, queryDef);
            var recordsEnumerator = records.Records.GetEnumerator();

            while (recordsEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                Record attributes = recordsEnumerator.Current as Record;

                for (int i = 0; i < attributes.Values.Count(); i++)
                    if (attributes.Values[i] is PolygonN)
                    {
                        PolygonN featureExtent = attributes.Values[i] as PolygonN;
                        // Problem here >>>
                        PointCollection vertices = featureExtent as PointCollection;
                     }
            }
```

Comment: any help? http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/18262-how-get-vertices-of-polygon